# How to create class instantiation like this $classINstance->childInstance->method() (like CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been thinking to make a class inheritance similar to that of CodeIgniter.

In codeIgniter, when you make a class, let's say:

```
class A 
{

}
```

Then anywhere in the models and controllers you can refer to it:

```
$this->A->methods();
```

How this is implemented?
I thought it is done through extending, but I have checked it and it is not the technique.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html There is no inheritance. Objects are created and assigned to the controller so they can be accessed using $this->A. Note that this does not allow multiple instances of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class A{

public $b;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->b = new B;
  }
}

Class B {
  public function someFunction() {
    .........
  }
}
```

Now you can use it as following:

```
$a = new A;
$a->b->someFunction();
```